# array_merge overwrite array with key-value structure

Tags: php, arrays, key-value, array-merge

I got this array named `$records`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [name] => name1
            [publisher] => Dieter
            [date] => 2022-07-29
            [text] => blablablablablablablablablabblablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [name] => name2
            [publisher] => Dieter
            [date] => 2022-07-28
            [text] => awhduawohduawohduawhduawuhdawhduaiwd
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [name] => name3
            [publisher] => Dieter
            [date] => 2022-07-30
            [text] => blub
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [name] => name4
            [publisher] => Dieter
            [date] => 2022-07-31
            [text] => awdawdw
        )
)
```

and then I want to filter them by their ids(`$ids=[14,16]`):

```
$articles = array();
foreach ($records as $article) {
    if (in_array($article['id'], $ids)) { //alg select only one article
        $articles = array_merge($articles, $article);
    }
}
    return $articles;
```

and the Output should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [name] => name1
            [publisher] => Dieter
            [date] => 2022-07-29
            [text] => blablablablablablablablablabblablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [name] => name2
            [publisher] => Dieter
            [date] => 2022-07-28
            [text] => awhduawohduawohduawhduawuhdawhduaiwd
        )
)
```

But I got this:

```
Array
(
       [id] => 16
       [name] => name2
       [publisher] => Dieter
       [date] => 2022-07-28
       [text] => awhduawohduawohduawhduawuhdawhduaiwd
)
```

This command doesnt work because I get a diffrent structure:

```
array_merge_recursiv()
```

Comment: You should just push the article onto the array, not merge it.

Comment: `$articles[] = $article;`

Comment: you can also use `array_filter()`.

Comment: As already stated, this is more than simple to do with [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) - see [an example over on 3v4l](https://3v4l.org/vgsOm)

Answer (score 0):

```
$articles = array();
foreach ($records as $article) {
    if (in_array($article['id'], $ids)) { //alg select only one article
        $articles[] =  $article;
    }
}
    return $articles;
```

`array_merge` is not needed here, you can push a new entry in your table using `$articles[]`.

You can also keep keys of the original table like that :

```
$articles = array();
foreach ($records as $key => $article) {
    if (in_array($article['id'], $ids)) { //alg select only one article
        $articles[$key] =  $article;
    }
}
    return $articles;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_diff_column_values($rawArray, $searchArray, $columnName = 'id') {
    $result = [];

    foreach($rawArray as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($value[$columnName]) && in_array($value[$columnName], $searchArray)) {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_diff_column_values($records, [14,16]));
echo "</pre>";
```